# Display a value from a different object in a GridView column

Tags: gridview, dotvvm

I have a  element bound to a Projects object. The Project object has a ClientId property that is linked to a Client object. The Client object has two properties; the Id property which is linked to the ClientId property and a Name property. I can easily display the ClientId from the Project object, but I want to display the Name property from the Client object.

I have tried using a  element with a DataSource set to a collection of Clients. I have set the Item* attributes with values from the Clients object. The Value attribute (which is required and what is displayed) cannot see Clients object so I cannot display the value in the Name property in the Client object.

from ViewModel both properties are correctly initialized and filled

```
public BusinessPackDataSet<MasonAndHangerWebApi.Models.BimCimData.Project> Projects { get; set; }

public IList<MasonAndHangerWebApi.Models.BimCimData.Client> Clients { get; set; }
```

from View

```
<bp:GridView DataSource="{value: Projects}" ...>
...         
<bp:GridViewComboBoxColumn DataSource="{value: Clients}"
                                       HeaderText="Client"
                                       ItemKeyBinding="{value: _parent.ClientId}"
                                       ItemTextBinding="{value: Name}"
                                       ItemValueBinding="{value: Name}"
                                       Value="{value: Cannot see values from the Clients datasource }" />
...
</bp:GridView>
```

What do I need to do to display the Name value from the Client object in this GridView?

Answer (score 0):

I wound up using a Dictionary with the (long)Id in the Key and the string display value in the Value.

```
<bp:GridViewTextColumn HeaderText="Client"
                                   Value="{value: _root.ClientNames[ClientId]}"
                                   AllowSorting="True" />
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, a better approach is to prepare the objects for the GridView in the exact format you need.

Create a new class which contains all properties the GridView need, and to aviod a lot of code that will transform the data, you can use AutoMapper or a similar library.

```
public class ProjectDisplayDto
{
    // all properties from the Project class

    public string ClientName { get; set; }

}
```

In AutoMapper configuration, you just need to create a mapping. The properties which have the same names and types, will be mapped automatically. You only need to define the rules to map the extra ones.

```
mapper.CreateMap<Project, ProjectDisplayDto>()
    .ForMember(p => ClientName, m => m.MapFrom(p => ...));  // tell AutoMapper how to get the client name
```

If you are using Entity Framework and `Project` class is an entity, you'll probably have the Client navigation property present in this class. If the `Client` has the Name property, AutoMapper will figure out the mapping automatically, so you don't even need to configure the rule for the `ClientName` property.

It may look like that using this approach a lot of unnecessary classes are created. But in case of larger applications, I see that as an advantage, because often you need to add a column on one screen and having a separate class for that means that you don't affect other screens in the application.